# Cassandra - When inserting text using the CLI, What characters need escaping?

Tags: cassandra, command-line-interface

I am trying to insert HTML as text value in a Cassandra db, using the CLI. I get all sorts of error messages that are not very helpful, but I know the errors occur because I need to escape certain characters. I already have escaped quotes and double quotes. What else needs to be escaped? In short what are the escaping rules for inserting text using the Cassandra CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to find the solution. The only characters that needed escaping were quotes and double quotes. The problem was with the line feeds. I removed all line feeds from my html data and the value inserted correctly.